# How can i catch the sucessfull response in rxjs and return some specific value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code

```
let arrApi = [];

arrApi.push(this.securityService.deleteBusinessDataRule('1000').pipe(catchError(error => of({error: true}))))

forkJoin([...arrApi]).subscribe((forking: any) => {
            console.log('forking', forking);
        });
```

so I am building dynamically api request throught `arrApi`.
The method `(this.securityService.deleteBusinessDataRule('1000')`
returns observable. It is delete reqquest which get 204 as status code.
If there is some error inside i am catching the error so in `forking[0]`

i will get `error: true` as a value because i catched the error in the observable and i will use it.

I don't know how can i catch the response when it is sucessfull ?
So when the observable passes i want to emit value like {error: false}
because this delete request does not return anything in the response after i hit the delete API
and i keep getting undefined in `forking[0]`.

So everytime when the observable is competed I need to get {error: false}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `map` operator from rxjs:

```
arrApi.push(
  this.securityService.deleteBusinessDataRule('1000')
    .pipe(
      map(()=>({error: false})),
      catchError(error => of({error: true}))
  )
)
```

Comment: actually, static mapTo would do.

Comment: unfortunately mapTo is deprecated and will be removed in v9: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mapTo

Comment: @FabianStrathaus why when i try to used - =>{error: false} the value is not returned directly ? I used one line code so => {error:false} but it works with => return {error:false} why is that ?

Comment: in `=>{error: false}` the curly brackets are interpreted as function body. If you want them to be interpreted as a JSON object, you have to wrap them in brackets like `=>({error: false})`

Comment: @FabianStrathaus thank you very much.I tried with map but directly without wrapping it in () and that is why it did not worked...